# User has to be given access to log file

Tags: asp-classic, vb6, iis-6

Please see the code below:

```
strLines = Split(strData, vbCrLf)
    lngLinesRead = UBound(strLines)
    intFile = FreeFile
    Open "log.txt"For Append As #intFile
    Print #intFile, Now & " ***************** Start of import. User: " & strUser & " on: " & strTerminal & " ******************** "
    Close #intFile
```

This is VB6 code called from a Classic ASP application.  The Identity of the application pool that runs the app is: NETWORK SERVICE.  However, in order to use the app; the end users login has to be given access to: log.txt.  Why is this? Is it not NETWORK SERVICE that writes to the log file?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving write permissions to the IIS_WPG group.

Comment: Why would I have to do this? Networkservice is running the application pool.

Comment: "The IIS_WPG user is a the IIS Worker Process Group, and is needed in order for IIS to run / access applciations within a folder."